# How do I use more than one app on the same page but not all pages

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

So I have the standard django tutorial polls app and I made a little blog app. Is there a simple way to add a poll to some of the blog posts but not all.

I've found this:

```
from django.models.polls import polls
from django.models.blogs import posts

def my_view(request):
        return render_to_response("template_name", {
                "poll_list" : polls.get_list(),
                "post_list" : posts.get_list(),
        }
```

But how do I pick which poll I want in the template and if I add it to the template won't it show up in every post? I feel like im seriously over-thinking or under-thinking this. Any advice or links would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
models.py #for the blog app
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.TextField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def display_mySafeField(self):
        return mark_safe(self.body)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

views.py # for blog class
def post(request, pk):
    """Single post with comments and a comment form."""
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=int  (pk))
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
    d = dict(post=post, comments=comments, form=CommentForm(), user=request.user,
             months=mkmonth_lst())
    d.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("post.html", d)
```

I want to add a poll to a post but not all of them.

Comment: What does "some of the blog posts but not all" mean exactly?

Comment: I'll put up my models & views. Each post is a page with a title and body, I want to add a poll to the body of the post.

Comment: How will you indicate that you want a poll in the post?

Comment: I guess thats what I'm trying to figure out. Do I need to add something to the model or just pass the polls.get_list in the view to the template? Should I add a bool "hasPoll" and Int "pollID"? to the post model and then pass the list and use those two variables in the template?

Comment: So...... are you looking for some content you can add to the post in order to have the poll show up?

Comment: I was thinking of having a post and then after the body having a little poll like: "do you agree with this post? yes/no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add something which will indicate which poll is associated to which model. You can use `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField`, `GenericForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, etc and then use that indicator to get poll/s associated to post/s .

Comment: Will that work if they aren't in the same models.py? Can I link a model in one app to a model in another? Or should I just make one big ass models.py and views.py? Thats the part that is confusing me. I know how to link things to one post, that's what i did with the comments. I wanted to use the tutorial polls app with my blog app.

Comment: It doesn't matter they are in which `models.py`, You can relate any installed django-models.

Comment: So i just need to add post as a foreign key to my poll and a bool has poll to my post?

Comment: If you will use `ForeignKey` I don't thin you will need `BooleanField`.

Comment: K, thanks so much. I knew I over-thinking it, I didn't know you could do that across apps. Thanks again.

Comment: ok, so I got it to work but when I don't have a poll linked to that post the page crashes. I did this:post = Post.objects.get(pk=int(pk)) poll = Poll.objects.get(post=post) in my post view, if I filter it the poll comes up but none of the choices?

Comment: Improve your view. you can't get something that `DoesNotExist`. Use `exceptions` handling or use shortcuts like `from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404; post=get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)`. I also think yo need to read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/relations/).

Comment: I ended up doing:     try:
        poll = Poll.objects.get(post=post)
    except Poll.DoesNotExist:
        poll = None. It works, Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I think you also need to except `DoesNotExist` for post, and since polls are foreignkeyed to the Post, you don't need to query related polls manually (list of all related polls will be available automatically as `post.poll_set.all()`.), that's why I recommended you to read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/relations/) .